# MongoDB Realm App Services resetPassword for email users not working in Web SDK

Tags: javascript, mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform

MongoDB Realm App Services resetPassword for email users not working in Web SDK

I have a MongoDB Realm Application (or now App Service) that manages the users for my iOS App. For that iOS App i have implemented a password reset function. I used the custom reset function that is called with `callResetPasswordFunction()` from my iOS App. The function itself only sends a custom email to the user which contains the token, tokenID and user attribute as well as a link to my website.

On my Website (Wordpress) i want to embed some HTML that calls the Realm WebSDK's `resetPassword()` function to set a new password for the user.

The Problem is, that my HTML and JS code is only working in Chromes Incognito mode. Other Browsers (e.g. Safari or Chrome on iPhone) run into an error (Safari console):

[image]

I am not quite sure what the problem is, but it seems that there is a problem to load the REALM Web SDK (maybe due to CORS restrictions).

Here's the HTML and JS Code i have embedded on my website:

```
<form>
    <label for="neuesPasswort">New Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="neuesPasswort" name="neuesPasswort" required><br>
  
    <label for="passwortBestaetigen">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="passwortBestaetigen" name="passwortBestaetigen" required><br>
  
    <button type="submit">Change Password</button>
  </form>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/realm-web/dist/bundle.iife.js"></script>
  <script>
  
    // initialize Realm
    const app = new Realm.App({ id: 'example_realm_ID' });
  
    // get transaction data from URL parameters
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const token = params.get('token');
    const tokenId = params.get('tokenid');
    const email = params.get('user');

  
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
      //event.preventDefault();
  
    const newPassword = document.getElementById('neuesPasswort').value;
    const confirmPassword = document.getElementById('passwortBestaetigen').value;
    
      if (newPassword === confirmPassword) {
        try {
          await app.emailPasswordAuth.resetPassword({
            password: newPassword,
            token,
            tokenId,
            });
          alert('Success!');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          alert('Error. Please try again.');
        }
      } else {
        alert('Passwords don't match!');
      }
    });
  
  </script>
```

EDIT: App services / Realm console does not show a failed function call in the logs or similiar for the occured errors. It shows successful logs for chrome incognito mode.